# Class 'Twig_Test' not found

Tags: php, twig

I have a web app in a development environment, pushed to a git repository, and pulled to a deployment environment.  Except for a few settings (such as my database credentials), it's all the same code.  I'm using Twig, installed with Composer, for templates.

In my development environment, it all works fine.  Deployed I get a the error: Class 'Twig_Test' not found.  I can't find a Twig_Test class or interface anywhere in the Twig code.  But it all works (without such a class or interface) in my development environment.  And yes, it is finding the Composer autoload:  The error is generated at \vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Extension\Core.php (line 203) which would not have been found without the autoload.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect on your website in production with ssh and make the command line composer install.

Comment: Well, I did try "composer update":.  That didn't help.  I guess I could go back and try "composer install" to see if that would work any better.  However, I figured out it was a problem with my ..gitignore.  It's all working now.  But thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Oh ugh (and a few other choice words).  The file vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Test.php got caught by something in my .gitignore and never made it to the deployment environment.  As Emily Litella used to say, "Never mind!"